# TestFlight version numbers

Tags: ios, versioning, apple

If I update an iOS app as a result of tester feedback during TestFlight, should I be updating the "marketing" version number, or just the build number?

My current (initial) version number is X.Y.Z where Z is currently 0 and X.Y are out of my control (because they relate to the version of the upstream non-iOS product that my port is based upon).   My preference is to keep the .Z part for "public" releases and use the build number to indicate releases in between.

What I don't know is whether doing so affects the way that Apple handle the app.

Does it make a difference if those updates are just bug fixes, or feature enhancements?

Comment: Does anyone except for the dev's get to see the update? Then I'd update the marketing version number. If not, it's up to you. Some users tend to get confused though, if they miss out on version numbers.

Comment: @randy I've added more detail

Comment: It sounds like the core question is what Apple does with different version numbers, which is something only they can answer authoritatively. Any guess we make here is bound to be either incomplete, out of date or purely speculative.

Comment: well, apart from having to "cancel" the release of build 1 first, I was able to upload build 2, and then having ticked the box that said "no significant changes" that build was then immediately open to the beta testers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every release to customers should have a new version number. Every release to testers should have a new build number. Customers will think something is wrong if version numbers are missing, so a sequence of version numbers could be for example 1.3.0, 1.3.1, 1.3.2, 1.4.0 etc.

Comment: Hmm, OK, I tried that, but it seems that since my X.Y.0 build 1 already went through beta review by Apple I can't now upload X.Y.0 build 2 :(

Comment: I was able to upload build 2 by cancelling the release of build 1